# MockMvc + Mockito: how to mock HttpServletRequest object in method call with MockMvc

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito, spring-test

```
 public class Test

      @Autowired
      private MagicGetter getter;

      @RequestMapping("/test")
      public void handleTest(HttpServletRequest request) {
           Magic magic = getter.get(request);
           magic.perform();
      }
 }
```

`handleTest` is the method I want to test, so I wrote this test

```
@Test
public void testTest()
        throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/test"));
}
```

I will get NPE from `magic.perform()`, so I have to do this to get rid of it. (assuming that I have `Getter`, `Magic` `@Mock`ed and `@InjectMock`ed to `Test`)

```
when(getter.get(any(HttpServletRequest.class))).thenReturn(magic);
```

Is there a way to avoid using `any`?

Comment: why do you want to avoid using `any`??

Comment: @Hilikus because in a multi-param method call, I have to put `any` on all of the params. I would prefer using mockito mocked object still.

Comment: but you are actually calling the method that you are mocking, how else would it compile if you don't pass a parameter that the method is expecting?? and what do you mean with your last sentence?? you are actually preparing your mock so yo *do* use it